# Roots of $f(x) = x^3+x^2-2x-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Roots of $f(x) = x^3+x^2-2x-1$

Show:

- $a_1=2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})$ is a root of $f$. [Edited here]
- $a_2 = a_1^2-2$ is a root of $f$.
- $a_3 = a_1^3-3a_1$ is a root of $f$.

---

The first one is easy, since $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{7}}$ is a root of $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{6}{x^i}$, and $f(a_1)$ is the real part of $p(a_1)$.

But I don't understand how to conclude the other two solutions/roots.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the equation ?

Comment: Show $a_1+a_2+a_3=-1,\,\,,a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3=-2,\,\,a_1a_2a_3=1$

Comment: I edited the question, $a_1$ is $2cos(...)$ and not $cos(...)$

Comment: Hamid, thanks for commenting, I guess I need more directioning...

Answer (score 0):

We have $3$ proposed roots, and a cubic equation. We calculate:

$(x - a_1)(x - a_2)(x - a_3) = (x - a_1)(x - (a_1^2 - 2))(x - (a_1^3 - 3a_1))$

$= x^3 - (a_1 + a_1^2 - 2 + a_1^3 - 3a_1)x^2 + (a_1(a_1^2  - 2) + a_1(a_1^3 - 3a_1) + (a_1^2 - 2)(a_1^3 - 3a_1))x - a_1(a_1^2 - 2)(a_1^3 - 3a_1)$

$= x^3 - ((a_1^3 + a_1^2 - 2a_1 - 1) - 1)x^2 + (a_1^5 + a_1^4 - 4a_1^3 - 3a_1^2 + 4a_1)x  - (a_1^6 - 5a_1^4 + 6a_1^2)$

$= x^3 + x^2 + (a_1^2(a_1^3 - a_1^2 - 2a_1 - 1) - 2a_1 - 2a_1^2 + 4a_1)x - (a_1^6 - 5a_1^4 + 6a_1^2)$

$ = x^3 + x^2 + ((-2a_1)(a_1^3 + a_1^2 - 2a_1 - 1) - 2)x - (a_1^6 - 5a_1^4 + 6a_1^2)$

$= x^3 + x^2 - 2x - (a_1^6 + a_1^5 - 2a_1^4 - a_1^3 - a_1^5 - 3a_1^4 + a_1^3+ 6a_1^2)$

$= x^3 + x^2 - 2x  - (a^3(a_1^3 + a_1^2 - 2a_1 - 1) - a_1^5 - 3a_1^4 + a_1^3+ 6a_1^2)$

$= x^3 + x^2 - 2x + (a_1^5 + 3a_1^4 - a_1^3 - 6a_1^2)$

$= x^3 + x^2 - 2x + (a_1^2(a_1^3 + a_1^2 - 2a_1 - 1) + 2a_1^4 + a_1^3 - 5a_1^2)$

$= x^3 + x^2 - 2x + (2a_1^4 + a_1^3 - 5a_1^2)$

$= x^3 + x^2 - 2x + [(2a_1)(a_1^3 + a_1^2 - 2a_1 - 1) - a_1^3 - a_1^2 + 2a_1]$

$= x^3 + x^2 - 2x - (a_1^3 + a_1^2  - 2a - 1) - 1 = x^3  + x^2 - 2x - 1$

using the fact that $a_1^3 + a_1^2 - 2a_1 - 1 = 0$ repeatedly (since it is a root).

Hence $(x-a_2),(x-a_3)$ both divide $f$, and thus $a_2,a_3$ are roots of $f$.